# ScalaJS fastOptJS and start script with sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, sbt-native-packager, software-packaging

I'm working on a classic ScalaJS with Scalatags... app using the  cross build approach:

```
<root folder>
- client
- project
- server
- shared
- build.sbt
```

It works fine running `sbt re-start` or `sbt run-main WebServer`
Now, with the **sbt-native-pagkager** plugin I would like to package all the stuff and generate a start script for my project.

The start script generation works but the ScalaJS fastOptJs seems to be not included.

There is something that should help [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/scalajs.html) but definitely it doesn't in my case.

BTW, my **build.sbt** file looks like:

```
val scalaV = "2.12.2"

lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scalaV,
    scalaJSProjects := Seq(client),
    pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline),
    // triggers scalaJSPipeline when using compile or continuous compilation
    compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalaJSPipeline).value,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
    ),

    WebKeys.packagePrefix in Assets := "public/",
    (managedClasspath in Runtime) += (packageBin in Assets).value,
    // Packaging
    topLevelDirectory := None // Don't add a root folder to the archive
  )
  .enablePlugins(SbtWeb, JavaAppPackaging)
  .dependsOn(sharedJvm)

lazy val client = (project in file("client"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scalaV,
    scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := Seq((scalaSource in Compile).value),
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     ...
   ),
  jsDependencies ++= Seq(
     ...
  )
)
.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSWeb)
.dependsOn(sharedJs)

lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))
  .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
     scalaVersion := scalaV,
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        ...
     ),
     // build info
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.BuildTime,
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](
    ),
    buildInfoPackage := "com.example.build"
  )
  .jsSettings(
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
     )
  )
 .jsConfigure(_ enablePlugins ScalaJSWeb)

 ....
```

Any help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault!

I didn't reference within my html template the right javascript files (
client-jsdeps.min.js and client-opt.js) generated using `stage`

It works fine now!!